# How to send data from class to activity for imageAnalysis

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camerax

I have created a class for imageAnalysis for image processing using cameraX. But i don't know how to send live data from this class to my activity.

I need to get data here

**viewBinding.predictedTextView.text = valueFromClass**

Data that is to be sent

**val luma = pixels.average()**

Code for activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewBinding.predictedTextView.text = valueFromClass
   
    }


    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            imagePreview = Preview.Builder().apply {
                setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
                setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
            }.build()

            imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder().apply {
                setImageQueueDepth(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            }.build()
        
            imageAnalysis?.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer())

            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this,
                cameraSelector,
                imagePreview,
                imageAnalysis
            )
            imagePreview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
            cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
            cameraInfo = camera.cameraInfo
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

  
}
```

Code for class:

```
class LuminosityAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
     
            // Since format in ImageAnalysis is YUV, image.planes[0]
            // contains the Y (luminance) plane
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            // Extract image data from callback object
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()
            // Convert the data into an array of pixel values
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
            // Compute average luminance for the image
            val luma = pixels.average()
            // Log the new luma value
            Log.d("CameraXApp", "Average luminosity: $luma")
            // Update timestamp of last analyzed frame
            lastAnalyzedTimestamp = currentTimestamp
        
        image.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: pass a live data in the constructor or just use a callback whichever method you prefer.

Comment: @pintu236 could you explain more, i am new to this.

Comment: check this android codelab [CameraX codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#5)